# Radio Button if on click

Tags: javascript, html, forms, if-statement, radio-button

i want add if / else if in radio button when click

- if i click checked Radio Value "Radio 1"
  i can  click radio value "Radio Sub 1" or "Radio Sub 2"
  and Disable text box "more"
- if i click checked Radio Value "Radio 2"
  disable text box "more"  and disable radio value 
  "Radio Sub 1" or "Radio Sub 2" (Sub Radio)
- if i click checked Radio Value "Radio 3"
  i can type in text box "more" and disable radio value 
  "Radio Sub 1" or "Radio Sub 2" (Sub Radio)
- else i don't checked radio 
  must disable text box "more"  and disable radio value 
  "Radio Sub 1" or "Radio Sub 2" (Sub Radio)

This is my code

```
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="Radio 1" >
<label>Radio 1</label> &nbsp; &nbsp;

<input type="radio" name="mysubradio" value="Radio Sub 1"  >
<label>Radio Sub 1</label> &nbsp; &nbsp;

<input type="radio" name="mysubradio" value="Radio Sub 2"  >
<label>Radio Sub 2</label> &nbsp; &nbsp;
<br/><br/>

<input type="radio" name="myradio"  value="Radio 2" >
<label>Radio 2</label> <br/><br/>

<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="Radio 3" >
<label>Radio 3</label> 
<input name="more" placeholder="more" maxlength="50" type="text" >
```

You can test code in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ubmLydLL/) Js Fiddle

Help me, Thank's :)

Comment: Well, it's time to add some Javascript in it. See how javascript works, you will have to subscribe to the click events, and to do your "if" logic when a radio input is clicked.

Comment: iam newbie in javascript :(
can you help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, I have used jQuery but it is not the best way to learn JavaScript basics. So please use this solution as a demo to discover what you can do with JavaScript & jQuery, but when you will start to learn it, begin with JavaScript only.

This is what you can do to implement the logic you mentioned before :

```
$('input').click(function() {
// Will be equal to the value of the selected radio
var myradio = $('input[name="myradio"]:checked').val();

if (myradio === 'Radio 1')
{
    // Enable subradios
    $('input[name="mysubradio"]').prop('disabled', false);

    // Disable textbox
    $('input[name="more"]').prop('disabled', true);
}
else if (myradio === 'Radio 2')
{
    // Disable subradios
    $('input[name="mysubradio"]').prop('disabled', true);

    // Disable textbox
    $('input[name="more"]').prop('disabled', true);
}
else if (myradio === 'Radio 3')
{
    // Disable subradios
    $('input[name="mysubradio"]').prop('disabled', true);

    // Enable textbox
    $('input[name="more"]').prop('disabled', false);
}
});
```

I have updated your JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ubmLydLL/2/).
Now, I suggest you to start learning JavaScript with [tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) and then to discover [jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/) in order to understand the code I gave you.

Cheers